# Unbounded stationary sets in a regular cardinal

Tags: set-theory

Let $S$ be a stationary set in some regular, uncountable cardinal $\Omega$. Why is it the case that $S$ is unbounded in $\Omega$ if $\Omega$ is regular?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* For any ordinal $\alpha<\Omega$, $\{\beta\mid \alpha< \beta < \Omega\}$ is a club.